# SQL : SELECT * FROM method

Tags: c#, sql, for-loop, select

Just out of curiosity, how exactly does `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = "something"` works?

Is the underlying principle same as that of a `for/foreach` loop with an `if` condition like:

```
for (iterator)  
{
   if(condition)
      //print results
}
```

If am dealing with , say 100 records, will there be any considerable performance difference between the 2 approaches in getting the desired data I want ?

Comment: I believe sql use set based approach to fetch result whereas the loop is an iterative approach. Set based approach have higher performance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is SQL select usually implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055441/how-is-sql-select-usually-implemented)

Comment: Did I understand you correctly, you have about 100 records and want to know if to loop through this records in C# or take a database? If yes: for 100 records a database is completely overkill. Every connection will have more overhead than this loop

Comment: _"If am dealing with , say 100 records, will there be any considerable performance difference between the 2 approaches in getting the desired data I want ?"_ - Yes! The DBMS will pick the smartest way it can to execute the query. There are ways to even "help" the optimizer, but let's leave that out for a moment. If you fetch the data unfiltered and loop, you basically have to _transfer_ a lot of bytes, keep them in mem _and_ do the filtering yourself. So a basic rule of thumb: Let the DB do the filtering. In 99.9% of times, it will be more efficient.

Comment: ^^ _"dealing with 100 records"_ in the result or in the table? If you have 100 records in the table, you may not notice a considerable difference (but run your horses!). If you want to pick 100 out of millions of records - you bet you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL is a 4th generation language, which makes it very different from programming languages. Instead of telling the computer *how* to do something (loop through rows, compare columns), you tell the computer *what* to do (get the rows matching a condition).

The DBMS may or may not use a loop. It could as well use hashes and buckets, pre-sort a data set, whatever. It is free to choose.

On the technical side, you can provide an index in the datebase, so the DBMS can look up the keys to quickly to access the rows (like quickly finding names in a telephone book). This gives the DBMS an option how to acces the data, but it is still free to use a completely different approach, e.g. read the whole table sequentially.